# Do I have to reupload the binary after an appeal?

Tags: ios, app-store

I have uploaded to the app store an app. There wasn´t problems. The app was correctly reviewed.
But after an update, they rejected my app becouse of this:

```
2.12: Apps that are not very useful, are simply web sites bundled as apps, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may be rejected
```

It's an Augmented Reality app and the weird thing is that version 1.0 is almost the same that 1.1 (the update). I only added a lot of new scenes.
I have done the appeal right now but I don´t know if I have to reupload the binary. In my iTunes connect i can see this:

> The most recent version of your app has been rejected. Before
>   resubmitting it, visit the Resolution Center for details on
>   outstanding issues.

So I think I don't have to reupload but here in my university are all a little nervious...I only want to check if I'm wrong.

Thanks a lot for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you will not need to re-upload the binary. If the negotiations with Apple went well, the same binary that is already uploaded (v1.1) will be made available to AppStore.

Comment: Welcome, please tick the right answer to let others know the answer to the question.